# Difference in the rendering of css transition on transform property on an image between fireFox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-transitions, css-transforms

I animate an `img` in css with a bit of javascript that toggle a class. This class add a transform property to the `img` wich already have a transition. This way I make this image move from 0px to 10px in 3 seconds.

http://codepen.io/poolboy/pen/swcup

```
img {
  transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
}

img.trans {
  transform: translateX(10px) translateZ(0);
}
```

```
var myImg = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

setInterval(function(){
  myImg[0].classList.toggle('trans');  
}, 3000)
```

With Chrome this animation is smooth but the image become blurry. With Firefox, the transition is pixel by pixel (so not tha smoothy, we can see steps in the transition) but the image doesn't became blurry.

In this case the image have 3 seconde to move to +10px which mean that at the time of 1seconde of animation, the image should be at the distance of 3,33px from its start point.
Firefox seems to act like this : "3,33px is imposible, so I leave the image at 3px" (and if the image should be at 3,51px maybe he moves it to 4px).
Chrome seems to act more like this: "3,33px isn't possible so i try to rerender the image to make it but the image is degraded"

Not sure about my reasoning but the fact is, both of those animations are quite ugly, is there any solution when it comes to move image throug just a bit of pixel on a long duration ? Is it possible to have the same rendering between those two ?

Comment: I can't access the image - just times out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between Firefox and Chrome in this instance is that they have chosen two different methods of dealing with animation frames which do not end up on pixel boundaries.

The problem in Firefox is that they are only displaying images which are on pixel boundaries instead of transforming the image to what it would appear like if it was in between pixels. Such transformation is called interpolation. Given that they are not interpolating frames where the image is not on pixel boundaries, the displayed image only actually changes when it would be placed in the next full pixel.

The movement you have selected: 10 pixels over a 3 second period, leaves 0.3 seconds per pixel.  This is well above the [Flicker fusion threshold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold).  Thus, we humans experience it as individual distinct jumps form one pixel to another. In order for 10 pixels in 3 seconds to be experienced as smooth there must be additional frames displayed with the image interpolated to be as it would appear if the image was between pixels. Having the additional intermediate images allows your mind to perceive the movement as continuous.

Assuming we are attempting to get movement that looks smooth and are limited to only displaying images on pixel boundaries then we need to have enough intermediate images displayed during the transition time such that the rate of changes being show is higher than the flicker fusion threshold. While the flicker fusion threshold varies by a considerable number of factors, you can take a ballpark as to what movement rates begin to feel smooth to humans by knowing that video and movies are displayed at a minimum of about 24 images per second.

As a result, in this case, if you change the distance of the transition to an amount that results in a rate of change above the flicker fusion threshold you will see it as smooth. In 3 seconds, if we are going to move 1 pixel each change at 24 changes per second that is 72 pixels. A version of this example that moves the image 72 pixels in 3 seconds can be [found here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ulKpL). Obviously, you do not have to make all of your transitions only move at this rate. But you will have to experiment with the issue in mind to make it such that that the transition is smooth.

The reality is that computer animation can not consistently, or even usually, be smooth without interpolating frames which don't end up with images on pixel boundaries. Firefox should be doing interpolation to show images which are.

The issue with Chrome is almost certainly that they are using an algorithm for interpolating frames which results in a lower quality image. There are a variety of algorithms which can be used to perform interpolation of the source image into the representation which would make it look as if it has moved a small fraction of a pixel. In general, the algorithms which look better take more CPU time. In Chrome, Google made a choice of which algorithm to use (or possibly a set of algorithms from which it chooses one based on the CPU time available prior to having to meet the deadline of actually displaying a frame). The algorithm that was used made this image look blurry on your machine during the transition.

Unfortunately, there is, currently, no *official* way to affect how either browser performs interpolation during transitions.  The CSS property [`image-rendering`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images/#propdef-image-rendering) is supposed to be able to affect how interpolation is performed, however there is no way to force the browser to use a higher quality mode. This can be set to `image-rendering: optimizeQuality;`. Unfortunately, both the values `optimizeQuality` and `optimizeSpeed` are [deprecated and are in the process of being defined as synonyms to `auto`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images/#image-rendering). On the other hand, `auto` is intended to indicate a high quality appearance:

> [auto](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images/#valuedef-auto)
>       The image should be scaled with an algorithm that maximizes the appearance of the image. In particular, scaling algorithms that
>   "smooth" colors are acceptable, such as bilinear interpolation. This
>   is intended for images such as photos.

Using `auto`, the default, [explicitly does not prevent the browser](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images/#the-image-rendering) (user agent, UA) from choosing a lower quality algorithm during transitions (high CPU loading):

> This property does not dictate any particular scaling algorithm to be
>   used. For example, with image-rendering: auto, a user agent might
>   scale images with bilinear interpolation by default, switch to
>   nearest-neighbor interpolation in high-load situations, and switch to
>   a high-quality scaling algorithm like Lanczos interpolation for static
>   images that aren’t moving or changing.

**Workaround for Firefox**:

[[simonLeClerc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3699844/simonleclerc) found a workaround]:

If the image is rotated slightly (e.g. 1 deg) Firefox will use interpolation to render the image even during transitions. Ultimately this results in the movement appearing continuous.
There is an [**example on CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fmKoG).

JavaScript:

```js
    var myImg = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    
    setInterval(function(){
      myImg[0].classList.toggle('trans');  
      myImg[1].classList.toggle('trans');
      myImg[2].classList.toggle('trans');
    }, 3000);
```

```css
    img {
      transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    img.trans {
      transform: translateX(10px);
    }
    
    /*Adding a rotation causes FireFox to use interpolation to display the image on
     *  non-pixel boundaries. (resulting in the same blurry effect observe in 
     *  chrome)*/
    #myTestImage2 {
      transform: rotateX(1deg);
    }
    #myTestImage2.trans {
      transform: translateX(10px) rotateX(1deg);
    }
    
    /* Moving at 24 pixels/s. This means that there is a move to the next pixel with
     *   each frame at a rate of 24 moves per second.  This is enough for us to 
     *   perceive it as smooth motion.*/
    
    #myTestImage3.trans {
      transform: translateX(72px); ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
    <div>Transition (image not rotated)</div>
    <img id="myTestImage1"
            src="http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/549536saphRaw00.png" alt=""/>
    <div>A Rotated image with translation</div>
    <img id="myTestImage2"
            src="http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/549536saphRaw00.png" alt=""/>
    <div>Moving at 24 pixels/s</div>
    <img id="myTestImage3"
            src="http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/549536saphRaw00.png" alt=""/>
```

**Workaround for Firefox does not work when movement implemented as an animation**:

Unfortunately, the workaround does not succeed when the movement is implemented as a CSS animation ([**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/efwqC)):

```css
img {
}

#myTestImage1,#myTestImage2 {
  -webkit-animation: move10px 3s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
     -moz-animation: move10px 3s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
       -o-animation: move10px 3s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
          animation: move10px 3s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;

}

/* Moving at 24 pixels/s such that there is a move to the each frame more is 1/24*/

#myTestImage3 {
  -webkit-animation: move72px 3s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
     -moz-animation: move72px 3s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
       -o-animation: move72px 3s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
          animation: move72px 3s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

/*Adding a rotatation causes FireFox to use interpolation to display the image on non-pixel boundaries. (resulting in the same blurry effect observe in chrome)*/
#myTestImage2 {
  transform: rotateX(1deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes move10px { from { margin-left:0px; } to { margin-left:10px; }  }
   @-moz-keyframes move10px { from { margin-left:0px; } to { margin-left:10px; }  }
     @-o-keyframes move10px { from { margin-left:0px; } to { margin-left:10px; }  }
        @keyframes move10px { from { margin-left:0px; } to { margin-left:10px; }  }

@-webkit-keyframes move72px { from { margin-left:0px; } to { margin-left:72px; }  }
   @-moz-keyframes move72px { from { margin-left:0px; } to { margin-left:72px; }  }
     @-o-keyframes move72px { from { margin-left:0px; } to { margin-left:72px; }  }
        @keyframes move72px { from { margin-left:0px; } to { margin-left:72px; }  }
```

```html
<div>Animation (image not rotated)</div>
<img id="myTestImage1" src="http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/549536saphRaw00.png" alt=""/>
<div>A rotated image with animation</div>
<img id="myTestImage2" src="http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/549536saphRaw00.png" alt=""/>
<div>Animation moving at 24 pixels/s</div>
<img id="myTestImage3" src="http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/549536saphRaw00.png" alt=""/>
```